# Start/Stop Minecraft Server with PHP

Tags: php, shell, jar, minecraft, bukkit

For the last 10 hours I have been trying to find a way to start/stop a craftbukkit.jar file that is in the same directory as my php script. I have tried nearly all of the solutions I could find on stackoverflow and none of them worked.

I tried both `shell_exec("java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true");` and `exec("java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true");` I also tried putting the `java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true` in a external start.sh file and then running it with `exec("start.sh")`

What am I doing wrong? It is supposed to create all of the bukkit configuration files when the process is ran (just like it would when you run it on your computer)

Comment: What is happening when you try those various things? Are you getting any error messages? Have you tried manually changing to the appropriate directory before running `java`?

Comment: I'm getting absolutely no error messages. What do you mean by your second question?

Comment: I mean have you tried using `cd` first or giving java a full path to the jar file? Have you tried redirecting standard output and standard error to a file in those commands to see what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a console to run the server in...
i would reccomend a screen session for the server:

To start the server the command could look like this:

```
exec("screen -S bukkit sh /home/user/bukkit/start.sh")
```

the -S option is to name the session.
so when you want to connect to the console through ssh for example you simply do

```
screen -r bukkit
```

maybe you should use absolute paths for the command... not shure if its better or not

there is a way to send some commands to that session to stop the server as well... but i dont remember right now!

if you do not use screen for smth else you could try

```
exec("killall screen")
```

to kill all screensessions...
but be careful with that because the server might not save recent changes(no shutdown of the bukkit-server)

Comment: Could I change the path `/home/user/bukkit/start.sh` to only `start.sh`, since its in the same directory as the script? I'm testing the script on a shared host, could that be the problem?

Comment: I guess it could work with relative path... but its more relieable with absolute path

Comment: This is my start.sh file: `java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui` Any ideas why it does not work when ran via `exec("screen -S bukkit sh start.sh");`

Comment: Try to put this into the start.sh:
    cd Bukkit
    java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
Then use ecec("screen -S bukkit sh start.sh")

Comment: cd Bukkit is first line, the rest in second line

Comment: still seems not to work, could this be because its on a shared hosting account?

Comment: what host do you use, and what is the package you "pay" for?

Comment: If it is only a website hoster theres no chance of starting such a program.

Comment: I have a shared hosting account at host.bg, as well as an unmanaged VPS at DigitalOcean, going to try it on the VPS and see if it works.