# Start Gameserver (and other batch files) through PHP

Tags: php, cmd, server, exec, minecraft

I have a Windows Server with XAMPP (Apache 2.4 and PHP 7 running) and **i want to build a PHP script that can start and stop a few game servers on the same machine.**

---

I am struggling with the **Minecraft Server** right now, so let's take this as an example:

I have a folder called `C:\_tekkitlite` where the minecraft server is in. In these folder are these files (and a few others which are unimportant):

```
launch.bat
minecraft_server.jar
TekkitLite.jar
```

---

The `C:\_tekkitlite\launch.bat` has the following code in it:

```
java -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar TekkitLite.jar nogui
pause
```

---

My current `C:\_xampp\htdocs\startserver.php` looks like this:

```
system('C:\_tekkitlite\launch.bat');
```

---

When I execute the line above, I get the following message

```
C:\_xampp\htdocs>java -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar TekkitLite.jar nogui C:\_xampp\htdocs>pause Dr�cken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

The problem is that there is no java process running on the machine and consequently the minecraft server is offline.

---

When I change the `C:\_xampp\htdocs\startserver.php` to the following:

```
system('java -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar C:\_tekkitlite\TekkitLite.jar nogui');
```

i get no message from php (i think because there is no `pause` at the end of this code) BUT i get a java process and a server running.

The problem is that you cannot join this server because it seems that the server doesnt do anything. Normally a minecraft server creates a bunch of files after starting, mine doesn't when I start it with the script above.

---

From now on, I dont know what to do. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

I think the permissions are not a problem because when I create a batch on `C:` with

```
echo "TestTestTestTest"
pause
```

php outputs this TestTestTestTest just fine.

Comment: Hey I know absolutely nothing about minecraft servers but have you looked at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963868/start-stop-minecraft-server-with-php

Comment: This doesn't work. The command promt says that there is no command like `screen`. Do I have to install that? I searched for this quite a while but didn't find anything for windows.